# How do I fix signin error with firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to create simple sign-in flow using firebase-ui. I am using google as my authentication. I am following instructions from https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react

This is my src/login.js

```
// Import FirebaseAuth and firebase.
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Configure Firebase.
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Configure FirebaseUI.
const uiConfig = {
  // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  // Redirect to /signedIn after sign in is successful. Alternatively you can provide a callbacks.signInSuccess function.
  signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
  // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
};

function SignInScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Playground</h1>
      <p>Please sign-in:</p>
      <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignInScreen
```

This is how my index.js looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import SignInScreen from './login.js'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SignInScreen />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

When I run this, I get following error as seen in chrome

> [  2.159s] [firebaseui] Internal error: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","errors":[{"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
> console. @ index.js:1

I have supplied API key from

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Great; Do you know how to open DevTools Console?

Comment: No. If you can help, that will be great.

Comment: What is your Browser?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: Follow this [Article](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console) to open Devtools Console. After that tell me?

Comment: I figured out how to go developer tools in chrome. I see following error
[ 33.809s] [firebaseui] Internal error: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","errors":[{"message":"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}} 

But I am using correct API from my firebase project page.
Default GCP resource location 
Not yet selected
Web API Key
xxxx

Comment: Add that error in question as text rather than the old error.

Comment: updated the question with the error

Comment: Click the grey check mark next to my answer or your answer (The most answer that helped you) To help new people in Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that `The API Key` that you are using is uncorrect or invalid.

1. Check correctly for the `The API Key` and copy it correctly and slowly
   beacause you might copied it wrong. Also copy it from Firebase Console.
2. If you have more than one `API Key` (Or more than Firebase project or Google
   Cloud project) You might conflicted between them which might create this
   problem.
3. Try `REGENERATE KEY` in Google Cloud Console like this screenshoot :

[image: Google Cloud Console]

4. Go to Firebase Console then go to Authorized domain and add the Live Server (Domain) that you are using like `localhost:`

This is all possible solutions to solve this problem.

Big Thanks for this [Thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/issues/57).

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed my npm and started again and it worked. Not sure what was the issue. But the same code works now.